# why does variable hoisting occurs in JavaScript, in terms of execution context

Tags: javascript

I came to know variable hoisting is because of some steps in execution context.
So why does variable hoisting occurs in JavaScript, in terms of execution context.

Comment: It's a part of the syntax, that's why it works how it works.

Comment: Yeah its the way Javascript designed.. or maybe you could ask Brendan..

Comment: While the question is valid (as far as I understand it), pretty much only Brendan Eich, the creator of JavaScript, can answer it. Or someone working on language specification. I don't believe they frequent Stack Overflow though. If you are simply asking how it works, that a different story.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is a pseudo-overview of how the interpreter evaluates the code:

> Find some code to invoke a function.
>
> Before executing the function code, create the execution context.
>   Initialize the Scope Chain.
>
> Create the variable object:
>
> Create the arguments object, check the context for parameters, initialize the name and value and create a reference copy.
>
> Scan the context for function declarations:
>
> For each function found, create a property in the variable object that is the exact function name, which has a reference pointer to the function in memory.
>
> If the function name exists already, the reference pointer value will be overwritten.
>
> For each variable declaration found, create a property in the variable object that is the variable name, and initialize the value as undefined.
>
> If the variable name already exists in the variable object, do nothing and continue scanning.
>
> Determine the value of "this" inside the context.
>
> Run / interpret the function code in the context and assign variable values as the code is executed line by line.

Let’s look at an example:

```
function foo(i) {
    var a = 'hello';
    var b = function privateB() {    
    };
    function c() {    
    }
}
foo(22);
On calling foo(22), the creation stage looks as follows:    
fooExecutionContext = {
    scopeChain: { ... },
    variableObject: {
        arguments: {
            0: 22,
            length: 1
        },
        i: 22,
        c: pointer to function c()
        a: undefined,
        b: undefined
    },
    this: { ... }
}
```

As you can see, the creation stage handles defining the names of the properties, not assigning a value to them, with the exception of formal arguments / parameters.

Once the creation stage has finished, the flow of execution enters the function and the activation / code execution stage looks like this after the function has finished execution:

```
fooExecutionContext = {
    scopeChain: { ... },
    variableObject: {
        arguments: {
            0: 22,
            length: 1
        },
        i: 22,
        c: pointer to function c()
        a: 'hello',
        b: pointer to function privateB()
    },
    this: { ... }
}
```

A Word On Hoisting

You can find many resources online defining the term hoisting in JavaScript, explaining that variable and function declarations are hoisted to the top of their function scope. However, none explain in detail why this happens, and armed with your new knowledge about how the interpreter creates the activation object, it is easy to see why. Take the following code example:

```
​(function() {

    console.log(typeof foo); // function pointer
    console.log(typeof bar); // undefined

    var foo = 'hello',
        bar = function() {
            return 'world';
        };

    function foo() {
        return 'hello';
    }

}());​
```

The questions we can now answer are:

Why can we access foo before we have declared it?
If we follow the creation stage, we know the variables have already been created before the activation / code execution stage. So as the function flow started executing, foo had already been defined in the activation object.
Foo is declared twice, why is foo shown to be function and not undefined or string?

Even though foo is declared twice, we know from the creation stage that functions are created on the activation object before variables, and if the property name already exists on the activation object, we simply bypass the deceleration.

Therefore, a reference to function foo() is first created on the activation object, and when we get interpreter gets to var foo, we already see the property name foo exists so the code does nothing and proceeds.
Why is bar undefined?

bar is actually a variable that has a function assignment, and we know the variables are created in the creation stage but they are initialized with the value of undefined.

[variable hoisting bible](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/)

Comment: You should make it more clear that the entire answer is copy-pasted from http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/.

Comment: I thought it is having complete solution of what he asked so I did this but if you say so I'm on it. Thanks.

Comment: I think @Akhilesh is right.